# Converting data frame in wide format to long format in python

Tags: python, pandas, logistic-regression

I tried to create a dataframe in wide format and then convert it into long format as mentioned here https://medium.com/@wangyuw/data-reshaping-with-pandas-explained-80b2f51f88d2

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Mode': ['car', 'car', 'car', 'air', 'air', 'car', 'car', 'air', 'air'],'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],'time.air': [2.8, 2.9, 2.2, 2, 1.8, 1.9, 2.2, 2.3, 2.1],'time.car': [3.4, 3.8, 2.9, 3.2, 2.8, 2.4, 3.3, 3.4, 2.9]})
```

Then when i use wide_to_long function using the following code, i do not get an output as desired:

```
l = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='time', i=['id'], j='alternate',sep=".")
```

can some one help me, where i am doing something wrong?

Comment: Show your desired ouput

Answer (score 1):

There is problem need integers for each category in columns names after `.`:

```
print(df)
  Mode  id  time.air  time.car
0  car   1       2.8       3.4
1  car   2       2.9       3.8
2  car   3       2.2       2.9
3  air   4       2.0       3.2
4  air   5       1.8       2.8
5  car   6       1.9       2.4
6  car   7       2.2       3.3
7  air   8       2.3       3.4
8  air   9       2.1       2.9
```

Solution replace categories to integers, apply solution and last `map` back:

```
c = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('time')]
cats = c.str.split('.', expand=True).levels[1]
mapping1 = {str(k):v for k, v in enumerate(cats)}
mapping2 = {v:k for k, v in mapping1.items()}

df.columns = df.columns.to_series().replace(mapping2, regex=True)
print (df)
  Mode  id  time.0  time.1
0  car   1     2.8     3.4
1  car   2     2.9     3.8
2  car   3     2.2     2.9
3  air   4     2.0     3.2
4  air   5     1.8     2.8
5  car   6     1.9     2.4
6  car   7     2.2     3.3
7  air   8     2.3     3.4
8  air   9     2.1     2.9
```

---

```
l = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='time', i='id', j='alternate',sep=".").reset_index()
l['alternate'] = l['alternate'].map(mapping1)
print (l)
    id alternate Mode  time
0    1       air  car   2.8
1    2       air  car   2.9
2    3       air  car   2.2
3    4       air  air   2.0
4    5       air  air   1.8
5    6       air  car   1.9
6    7       air  car   2.2
7    8       air  air   2.3
8    9       air  air   2.1
9    1       car  car   3.4
10   2       car  car   3.8
11   3       car  car   2.9
12   4       car  air   3.2
13   5       car  air   2.8
14   6       car  car   2.4
15   7       car  car   3.3
16   8       car  air   3.4
17   9       car  air   2.9
```

Answer (score 1):

By using suffix = '\w+' to change the format

```
l = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='time', i=['id'], j='alternate',sep=".", suffix='\w+')
```